# Bitwise shift left and right in the same statement

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Is `char c2=i1<<8>>24;` valid C syntax? (Where `i1` is and unsigned integer) Additionally, will it yield the result of shifting `i1` 8 bits left and 24 bits right respectively? I am unpacking a char previously stored in `i1`, along with three other chars.  Code below:

```
unsigned char b3 = 202;
unsigned char b2 = 254;
unsigned char b1 = 186;
unsigned char b0 = 190;
...


unsigned int i1=202;
i1=i1<<8;
i1=i1+254;
i1=i1<<8;
i1=i1+186;
i1=i1<<8;
i1=i1+190;
...

char c1=i1>>24;
char c2=i1<<8>>24;
```

Comment: Your edit was useful! can you actually post the code that combines the 4 `char`s into an `int`? A subtle bug might be lurking there.

Comment: @chqrlie amended as asked.

Comment: John Bollinger hit the bull's eye!  You should definitely declare `c1`, `c2` etc. as `unsigned char`.  You are manipulating byte values beyond 127, you are asking for trouble handling them with `char` type that might be signed by default.

Comment: He makes a great point! Thank you @John Bollinger

Comment: Even if storing `202` into a `char` doesn't do anything fishy, you still cannot expect that `c1 == b3` or `c1 == 202`, because `char` can be `signed` or `unsigned` depending on the compiler settings and platform defaults.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is fine (although hard to read) and it will be parsed as `c2 = (i1 << 8) >> 24`.

So it will left shift `i1` 8 positions, thereby shifting the leftmost 8 bits off the lefthand edge, and then right shift the result 24 positions, thereby shifting the rightmost 16 bits off the righthand edge. If that's what you wanted, then you're good. I'd use parentheses to make it more readable.

If you're just going to convert that to a `char`, it's not obvious why you feel the need to remove the high-order bits (although it is true that there may be architectures in which `int` and `char` are the same size.)

Also, as noted by John Bollinger, it is possible for the end result to be larger than can fit in a `char`, which is not well defined in the common case that `char` is a signed type. (That will be true even if `unsigned int` is 32 bits, because you technically cannot assign a value greater than 127 to an 8-bit signed character.)

Comment: Since the overall statement assigns the result to a variable of type `char`, it might be worth mentioning that the behavior of the assignment is undefined if `char` is a signed type and the value of the expression assigned to it is greater than `CHAR_MAX`.

Comment: @John Bollinger: not exactly undefined behaviour, but definitely worth mentioning: *C11 6.3.1.3 p3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.*

Comment: @chqrlie, yes, I was sloppy.  Implementation-defined != undefined.  Either way, though, it's better avoided.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: What chqrlie said, and I'd add that there are *lots* of programs out there which assume that `char* p = buf; int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) *p++ = c; ` is valid. (I've written stuff like that, and I'll bet you have, too :) ) (with appropriate buffer-overrun checks, obviously)

Comment: One more piece of evidence that the only consistent option for `char` is that it be `unsigned` by default (ie: `gcc -funsigned-char`)

Comment: @chqrlie: It's the perverse influence of a culturally-restricted alphabet on technology. If English had more letters, we wouldn't be in this position.

Comment: @rici I am packing multiple chars into an int and then unpacking them later on in the program, thus the conversion to a char.

Comment: Touché par la grâce !

Comment: @JohnBollinger: By the way, C++ is more generous: "For each value i of type unsigned char in the range 0 to 255 inclusive, there exists a value j of type char
such that the result of an integral conversion (4.7) from i to char is j, and the result of an integral conversion
from j to unsigned char is i." (3.9.1/1)

Comment: @rici, I'm sure I have indeed written such code as you describe, but [these days] when writing something not intended to be a one-off I do approach it more carefully.  If people knowingly choose not to do then that's their business, but I hope to reduce the number of people who don't know why they might want to do any differently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a valid syntax. It is a valid syntax also for signed `int i1`, in which case you can achieve filling the 'upper part' of the value with the bit from a chosen position.

Comment: right shifting a signed int is implementation-defined if the value is negative. So you can't rely on the sign extension in portable code.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, it's valid syntax. You can achieve the effect that I believe is desired more understandably and portably with:

```
unsigned char c2 = (i1 & 0xff0000) >> 16;
```

Comment: It would actually be a tad more understandable this way: `unsigned char c2 = (i1 >> 16) & 0xff;`

Comment: @chqrlie I couldn't decide which was more understandable, and I thought it would be more understandable to just pick one.

Comment: "portably" is all ready given up as code depends on a 32+ bit `unsigned int` as the C spec only obliges  16 bits or more.